# Validation Rule not working as expected

Tags: validation-rule

I just started (still learning) my career in Salesforce 3 months ago and am having trouble building a specific validation rule. The idea is to control who can change the ownership of a record.

As of now, it is allowing only The current owner to change it, system admins, sales operations and if a boolean field on the object is checked.

Currently, it is like this (and works):

```
AND( 
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId), 
    $User.Id != PRIORVALUE(OwnerId),  
    $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator', 
    $UserRole.Name != 'Sales Operations', 
    NOT(Bypass_Opportunity_Validation__c)
)
```

I am trying to add another exception. It the userrole contains CSM + manager or CSM + Director. I wrote the following:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId), 
    $User.Id != PRIORVALUE(OwnerId),  
    $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator', 
    $UserRole.Name != 'Sales Operations', 
    NOT(Bypass_Opportunity_Validation__c), 
    NOT( 
        AND( 
            CONTAINS($UserRole.Name, "CSM"), 
            OR( 
                CONTAINS($UserRole.Name, "Manager"), 
                CONTAINS($UserRole.Name, "Director") 
            )
        ) 
    )
)
```

I believe there might be something wrong with Salesforce because I built a simple one and it fails. For example:

This works: (I can edit it as a system admin)

```
AND( 
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId), 
    $User.Id != PRIORVALUE(OwnerId), 
    $Profile.Name != 'System Administrator' 
)
```

This doesn't work: (I cannot edit it as a CSM User)

```
AND( 
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId), 
    $User.Id != PRIORVALUE(OwnerId), 
    $Profile.Name != 'CSM User'
)
```

The profile exists. When I run a query like this:

`SELECT Name, Id FROM Profile WHERE Name LIKE '%CSM%'`

I get 1 result:

[image: screenshot]

Can you shed some light here?

Edit:  I am testing changing the owner from A to B. Using a third user with Profile "CSM User" and Role "CSM EMEA Manager". If user I am logged in as is a System Administrator, it allows me to change the owner. But not with the other. It gives me the error setup on this validation rule.

Comment: Welcome To SSE! In case of the two simple validation rules are you testing by changing the owner of the record and are all conditions matching?

Comment: Hi @SaiPraveenKakkirala,
Yes, I am testing changing the owner from A to B.
Using a third user with Profile "CSM User" and Role "CSM EMEA Manager".

Comment: And thank you for chipping in @SaiPraveenKakkirala :D

Comment: So only this validation rule is active on the object . `AND( 
    ISCHANGED(OwnerId), 
    $User.Id != PRIORVALUE(OwnerId), 
    $Profile.Name != 'CSM User'
) `. If only this os active you should not be getting the error

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala THANK YOU!! it was not a validation rule, but it sent me in the right direction. I was not being able to edit it due to the hierarchy setup. I tested on a different opp and it worked.

Comment: Hard coding profile names into such validation rules is an anti-pattern that should be avoided. Instead use [custom permissions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.custom_perms_overview.htm&type=5) that are assigned to relevant users via permission sets, permission set groups and/or profile.

Comment: Hi @PhilW, i didn't find a way to do it using permissions. Because I want everyone to be able to edit if they are the owner or a manager. And this only applies to that specific field.
So my way around was a validation rule. I can use the profile ID instead of the profile name to avoid future problems if someone renames the profile.

Comment: I meant that you should use a custom permission in the validation rule, as covered in [this blog](https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2021/allow-certain-users-to-edit-data-using-custom-permissions-in-validation-rules).

Comment: BTW using an ID likely won't work on sandboxes as the IDs change.

Comment: Thank you for that @PhilW.
Although, even after reading that post, I cannot adapt it into my need.
I want everyone to be able to edit IF they are the owners. So everyone needs permission to do it, and then I Check the PRIORVALUE(OwnerId)...
But if I just do the validation rule like that, it will block Sys Admins from editing it if they are not the owners. Hence why I am whitelisting that profile in the validation rule.

Comment: Custom permissions can be considered as either positive or negative. I.e. having the custom permission can enable or block an action. The validation rule can still apply the OwnerId checks, but instead of testing profile names, just check if the user has the "permission" and if they do and they are not the owner the validation fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @SaiPraveenKakkirala mentioned, the code was right and was supposed to work.
The problem was due to the hierarchy setup. The user I was using to test could not change that specific opportunity. I tested with a different one (owned by someone he manages) and it worked.